# How caching works for api calls?

Tags: wso2

I'm new to wso2 API manager and can not understand the caching mechanism for API calls.
even though i read the related documentation [here](https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/install-and-setup/setup/advance-configurations/configuring-caching/#key-cache) for hours but still confused.
can someone describe it?
i mean when i call an API from dev-portal with a token which generated for the application, what happens in the background?
how it checks if the token is valid or not and if its valid, how it cashes for next calls?!

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two types of tokens in OAuth2, i.e JWT tokens and opaque tokens. In the latest version of API Manager you can't find the opaque token as it is now removed from the product.

JWT access tokens are self-contained access token and the gateway itself can validate the access token without reaching the key manager who issued the access token. In the JWT case, when you access an API with the JWT access token, the gateway first checks the cache whether the access token is available. If it is not available then only the gateway validates the JWT token and adds to the cache. Once the token is validated the request goes to the backend of the API and client gets the response. When the next request comes with that token, as the token is available in the cache, the gateway won't validate the token again.

In the opaque token case, when the request comes with the opaque access token, gateway first checks the cache and if it is not available, then gateway talks to the key manager and validate the access token and then adds to its cache. When the second request comes with the same access token, as the token is available in the cache, the gateway won't talk to the key manager.

Answer (score 0):

When you make a call the generated access token will be cached. That's how generally it works. Go through the following documentation where it describes the configurations related to WSO2 APIM. By going through the part which explains cache mechanisms you will be able to get a proper understanding.
https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/next/reference/config-catalog/#gateway-token-cache